# ECC Queue input

Tags: rest, integration, servicenow

I am getting ECC QUEUE input status as error code: 501,with input error message exception in script evaluation can't convert into Target table updating incident rest API integration ServiceNow, can anyone help me how to get out from error?

Want to get rid off from this problem.